# What is 500 server error "cache fill open file" in browsers and how to resolve it?

Tags: firefox, browser-cache

Sometimes, in Firefox (7.0.1) on WinXP, I encounter following error for some websites:

```
 Server Error
 The following error occurred:

 [code=CACHE_FILL_OPEN_FILE] An internal error prevented the object
 from being sent to the client and cached. Try again later.

  Please contact the administrator.
```

What is causing this error & how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 500 error is an error in the web-server, to resolve it you have to report it to the person who administers that website.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) says

> ### 5xx Server Error
>
> The server failed to fulfill an apparently valid request.
>   Response status codes beginning with the digit "5" indicate cases in which the server is aware that it has encountered an error or is otherwise incapable of performing the request. Except when responding to a HEAD request, the server should include an entity containing an explanation of the error situation, and indicate whether it is a temporary or permanent condition. Likewise, user agents should display any included entity to the user. These response codes are applicable to any request method.
>
> #### 500 Internal Server Error
>
> A generic error message, given when no more specific message is suitable.

---

I've seen this associated with PHP and Blogspot, so there may be a PHP/Blogspot bug or server-side coding error that produces this message at the server end under some circumstances.

Comment: RedGrittyBrick, 
yes 500 indicates that server failed to serve a req. but its the [code=CACHE_FILL_OPEN_FILE] I was looking for.

Comment: @akjain: That message is generated by the server, so check the server logs and server software manuals for more details.

Comment: ok.. but since I don't know who is hosting that website & on which server, I will need to contact the support team.